# Is there any way to tell if a shell script was killed with signal 9

Tags: bash, shell-script, java, kill, signals

I have a bash script (called from a java program) that keeps getting killed. I always catch the `signal 15` with `trap` but then some other signal comes along that I suspect is `signal 9` but am in basically blind as to if it is really `signal 9`.

I know you can't `trap` `signal 9`, so is there any other way I can tell if `signal 9` is killing my shell script?

Comment: What is running the shell script? That process should have access to the `status` of the child process via `wait(2)` or something.

Comment: a java program that is running as a daemon started with upstart is running the shell script process

Comment: You could strace the program and look for a line that says "killed by SIGKILL" or do some auditd work with `-a entry,always -F arch=b64 -S kill -k kill_signals`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The exit status of a killed command should be the signal number plus 128.  So you can use the exit status to find out which signal killed you process.

I tested it like this on Linux in the shell:

```
print_exit_status_for_signal () {
  (
    sleep 1000
    echo Exit staus $? = signal $(( $? - 128 ))
  ) &
  sleep 1
  killall "${1:+-$1}" sleep
}
print_exit_status_for_signal
print_exit_status_for_signal 15
print_exit_status_for_signal 9
print_exit_status_for_signal KILL
print_exit_status_for_signal TERM
```

EDIT: Note that a program can decide to exit with any¹ value (so you have to decide how far you trust the exit status to be the effect of a signal):

```
for i in $(seq 256); do
  sh -c "exit $i"
  echo Program exited with $?
done
```

Footnote 1: On my systems exit codes are represented as unsigned 8-bit numbers so they wrap at 256=0.

Comment: Note that this is only reliable for signal 9 which can't be trapped. Other signals can be trapped by the program which can then exit with any value.

Comment: yes, as gnp told, the kill -9 cannot be traped

Comment: Do you have any sources?